# requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am getting a weird behavior in my CoordinatorLayout  I have an Activity which calls another Activity  However when I press back button in My app For 1st item it getting returned to the calling activity Correctly however for second Item I have to press back button two times and so on. heres my Xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinativelayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fontFamily="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_header_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/poster_image_view"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/release"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_image_view"
                android:text="@string/release_date"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/releaseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_image_view"
                android:layout_below="@id/release"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/star_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/star_32dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/releaseDate"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_image_view"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/star_image_view"
                android:layout_below="@id/releaseDate"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rating"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/releaseDate"
                android:text="@string/out_of_ten"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moviedescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/poster_image_view"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Heres the Fragment that is inflating the layout file

```
public class DetailMovieFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String BASE_URl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
    private static final String BUNDLE_INT = "DetailMovie";
    private int mItemPosition;
    private Format mFormatter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mItemPosition = getArguments().getInt(DetailMovieActivity.BUNDLE_ARGS);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_movie, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_app_bar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //TextView represents the Synopsis of the Movie
        TextView plot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moviedescription);

        //poster
        ImageView poster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.poster_image_view);

        TextView releaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.releaseDate);
        TextView rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);


        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout templayout = collapsingToolbarLayout;
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getOriginal_title());
        mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final Window window = getActivity().getWindow();

        //backDrop Poster
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_header_imageview);
        String header_image = MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getBackdrop_path();
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(BASE_URl + header_image).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Bitmap bmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Palette.Builder builder = new Palette.Builder(bmap);
                Palette palette = builder.generate();

                //Extracting Colors from the Image to set The ToolBar Color and  status bar Color
                int darkVibrantColor = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(R.color.darkPrimaryColor);
                int vibrantColor = palette.getVibrantColor(R.color.primaryColor);
                templayout.setContentScrimColor(vibrantColor);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    window.setStatusBarColor(darkVibrantColor);
                    window.setNavigationBarColor(vibrantColor);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
        collapsingToolbarLayout = templayout;

        rating.setText(String.valueOf(MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getVote_average()));
        //using MVC Pattern to get Poster Url and then Loading in ImageView
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getPoster_path()).into(poster);

        releaseDate.setText(MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getRelease_date());

        plot.setText(MovieDataList.get(getActivity()).getSingleResultByPosition(mItemPosition).getOverview());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Heres the stack trace

> 07-12 21:25:08.406  31106-31106/com.example.prathamesh.popmovies W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{3d069b8f V.E..... ......ID 0,0-720,112 #7f0e0070 app:id/detail_app_bar} during layout: running second layout pass
>   07-12 21:25:08.429  31106-31106/com.example.prathamesh.popmovies W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout{1ecffe1c V.ED.... ........ 0,0-720,600 #7f0e006e app:id/collapsing_toolbar} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
>   07-12 21:25:08.432  31106-31106/com.example.prathamesh.popmovies I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@a50e284 time:54288775

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it actually I was using onIntereceptTouch Listener in my recyclerview 
 which was not correctly Implemented 
heres the link for implementing it correctly

[RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831)